# Python Monte Carlo Simulation Loop

Tags: python, loops, random, simulation, montecarlo

I am working on a simple Monte-Carlo simulation script, which I will later on extend for a larger project. The script is a basic crawler trying to get from point A to point B in a grid. The coordinates of point A is (1,1) (this is top left corner), and the coordinates of point B is (n,n) (this is bottom right corner, n is the size of the grid).

Once the crawler starts moving, there are four options, it can go left, right, up or down (no diagonal movement allowed). If any of these four options satisfy the following:

1. The new point should still be within the boundries of the n x n grid
2. The new point should not be visited previously

the new point will be selected randomly among the remaining valid options (as far as I know Python uses the Mersenne Twister algorithm for picking random numbers).

I would like to run the simulation for 1,000,000 times (the code below runs for 100 only), and each iteration should be terminated either:

1. The crawler gets stuck (no valid options for movement)
2. The crawler gets to the final destination (n,n) on the grid.

I thought I implemented the algorithm correctly, but obviously something is wrong. No matter how many times I run the simulations (100 or 1,000,000), I only get 1 successful event wehere the crawler manages to get to the end, and rest of the attempts (99, or 999,999) is unsuccessful.

I bet there is something simple I am missing out, but cannot see it for some reason. Any ideas?

Thanks a bunch!

EDIT: Some typos in the text were corrected.

```
import random

i = 1 # initial coordinate top left corner
j = 1 # initial coordinate top left corner
k = 0 # counter for number of simulations
n = 3 # Grid size

foundRoute = 0 # counter for number of cases where the final point is reached
gotStuck = 0 # counter for number of cases where no valid options found
coordList = [[i, j]]

while k < 100:
    while True:
        validOptions = []

        opt1 = [i - 1, j]
        opt2 = [i, j + 1]
        opt3 = [i + 1, j]
        opt4 = [i, j - 1]

        # Check 4 possible options out of bound and re-visited coordinates are
        # discarded:

        if opt1[0] != 0 and opt1[0] <= n and opt1[1] != 0 and opt1[1] <= n:
            if not opt1 in coordList:
                validOptions.append(opt1)

        if opt2[0] != 0 and opt2[0] <= n and opt2[1] != 0 and opt2[1] <= n:
            if not opt2 in coordList:
                validOptions.append(opt2)

        if opt3[0] != 0 and opt3[0] <= n and opt3[1] != 0 and opt3[1] <= n:
            if not opt3 in coordList:
                validOptions.append(opt3)

        if opt4[0] != 0 and opt4[0] <= n and opt4[1] != 0 and opt4[1] <= n:
            if not opt4 in coordList:
                validOptions.append(opt4)

        # Break loop if there are no valid options
        if len(validOptions) == 0:
            gotStuck = gotStuck + 1
            break

        # Get random coordinate among current valid options
        newCoord = random.choice(validOptions)

        # Append new coordinate to the list of grid points visited (to be used
        # for checks)
        coordList.append(newCoord)

        # Break loop if lower right corner of the grid is reached
        if newCoord == [n, n]:
            foundRoute = foundRoute + 1
            break

        # If the loop is not broken, assign new coordinates
        i = newCoord[0]
        j = newCoord[1]
    k = k + 1

print 'Route found %i times' % foundRoute
print 'Route not found %i times' % gotStuck
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're never clearing out your visited locations. Change your block that breaks out of the the inner `while` loop to look something like this:

```
 if len(validOptions) == 0:
     gotStuck = gotStuck + 1
     coordList = [[1,1]]
     i,j = (1,1)
     break
```

You'll also need to change your block where you succeed:

```
if newCoord == [n, n]:
    foundRoute = foundRoute + 1
    coordList = [[1,1]]
    i,j = (1,1)
    break
```

Alternatively, you could simply place this code right before your inner `while` loop. The start of your code would then look like:

```
k = 0 # counter for number of simulations
n = 3 # Grid size  
foundRoute = 0 # counter for number of cases where the final point is reached
gotStuck = 0 # counter for number of cases where no valid options found
while k < 100:
    i,j = (1,1) 
    coordList = [[i,j]]
    while True:
        #Everything else
```

Comment: ahh... I messed it up when I placed the outer `while` loop latest. It seems I need more coffee... Thank you very much!